# iPhone : Textfields and NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsnumberformatter

I am making an app with multiple textfields. I would like when the user enters a number in the textfield, to automatically add the percent symbol when editing ends. Right now, the only way i know how to do that is to convert the text value to float, then use NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle and then send back the value. I guess that there should be a simpler and faster way to do that for multiple textfileds. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate)'s `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method.

For example:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSString *oldTextFieldValue = textField.text;

    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %%",oldTextFieldValue];
}
```

Note the double "%" in the `stringWithFormat:` method: this is because a single % on its own is a "[format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)" and will not be taken into account and xcode will give you a warning, so you need to protect it with a second %.